# ¿Como darle formato decimal a un EditorFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sqldatatypes

Mi codigo en la vista

```
@Html.EditorFor(model = model.Debe, new{htmlAtributes = new{@class="form-control bor"}})
```

El error que me muestra

```
System.InvalidOperation.Exception:'The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type'System.Decimal'.'
```

El modelo de la vista

```
[Required]
public decimal Debe {get; set;}
```

Comment: Pudieras mostrar mas código de tu vista y de tu controlador? Estas pasando una lista a tu vista? Recibes una lista en tu método de acción en tu controlador?

Comment: @KodiakMx El problema era en el controlador, pero ya lo solucione, Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma simple de aplicarle formato es definiendo la cultura que se aplica al sitio web

```
<system.web>
     <globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es" />
     ...
</system.web>
```

de esta forma aplicaria la como como separador de decimales cuando visualices un valor numerico en la view